# JSON received in view but unable to render it in select option in jade

Tags: json, node.js, pug

I have following view in jade where it shows json cities but when looped in to get cityName it's empty

```
  p #{cities}
  p
    label(for='from') From
    select#sourcecity(name="sourcecity", required="required")
      each sourceCity in cities
        option(value="#{sourceCity.cityId}") #{sourceCity.cityName}
```

p #{cities}

```
[{"cityId":79,"cityName":"Lenggong"},{"cityId":64,"cityName":"Gemas"},{"cityId":87,"cityName":"Jerteh"},{"cityId":36,"cityName":"LCCT"},{"cityId":95,"cityName":"Genting Highlands"},{"cityId":57,"cityName":"Pengkalan Kubor"},{"cityId":2,"cityName":"Kuala Lumpur"},{"cityId":3,"cityName":"Melaka"},{"cityId":15,"cityName":"Seremban"},{"cityId":28,"cityName":"Kangar"},{"cityId":63,"cityName":"Bahau"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you seem to suggest that `p #{cities}` renders what *looks* to be an object, I think that you're passing a JSON *string* into Jade.

So something like this:

```
res.render('page', {
  cities : '[{"cityId":79,"cityName":"Lenggong"},...]'
});
```

But Jade requires an actual object to be passed:

```
res.render('page', {
  cities : JSON.parse('[{"cityId":79,"cityName":"Lenggong"},...]')
});
```